# Using Stripe How can i store card details of my customers and later on can charge them manually ....?

Tags: stripe-payments

```
    $stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(
  'sk_test_123'
);
$stripe->customers->create([
  'description' => 'My First Test Customer (created for API docs)',
]);
```

> SHOULD I START WITH CREATING A CUSTOMMER ?? AND THEN SENDING AN INVOICE LATER ON.

Comment: I advise you to remove your `sk_test_` from your question, and also to re-generate your secret key in stripe dashboard!

Answer (score 2):

You should follow the docs for [saving a card during payment](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-during-payment) or [saving a card without payment](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse), depending on your needs. Both include samples for [charging the saved card later](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-during-payment#web-create-payment-intent-off-session).